# How to examine an Array for .Text values

Tags: c#, arrays, tic-tac-toe

This is for a tic tac toe game where the grid can be sized to any number (3x3 4x4 8x8 etc)

When the form loads, a method reads the grid size and populates the form with that many buttons in a 1 dimensional Button Array. The Array is called buttonArray.

With just using the 1-dimensional buttonArray and without using LINQ, how can i compare the .Text values of buttons in buttonArray to see if they are either "X" or "O" for a CheckWinner() function.

After the button grid is created, I have an event handler for button clicks :

```
private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        b.Text = "X";
        b.Enabled = false;
        CheckWinner(buttonArray);
}
```

I am then calling my CheckWinner function and passing in the array buttonArray.

Again, I am just looking for a primitive way to check/compare values without using LINQ. If I know the length of each side of the grid, I can say that for Horizontal win lines, I am looking for that many buttons in a row with "X" as their .Text property.

So if I have a grid of 5x5, and I have 25 buttons in buttonArray, how can i check every 5 starting at the 0 index of the grid for their .Text values being "X" and then print a message if 5 in a row are the same, or "X" in this case.

```
for (int z = 0; z < root; z++) //increments the column to start on
        {
            vCount = 0; //Starts the win counter at zero when moving to the next column
            for (int i = z; i < arrLength; i=i+root) //starts at the first column and increments it by root to test the next button in the column
            {
                string bText = buttonArray[i].Text;
                if (bText == "X")
                    vCount++;
                if (vCount == root)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Vertical row winner found !");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }//end of vertical column test
```

I did the vertical test like that? But I think combining them into one would def be better.

Comment: Do you consider diagonal or only horizontal and vertical winning conditions?

Comment: Yeah absolutely but I figured just starting with a simple horizontal would be the easiest and I could go from there.

Comment: Well what is the winning condition for the 5x5? Only full diagonal?

Comment: 5 in a row, either horizontal [0-4][5-9][10-14]etc
vertical [0,5,10,15,20] etc
diagonal [0,6,12,18,24]
and      [4,8,12,16,20]
if a variable side is equal to the amount of buttons on one side of the grid, so side=5 in the 5x5 grid
Then diagonals would be [0,side+1,2*(side+1),3*(side+1),4*(side+1)]

Comment: I'm just looking for how I can pass in the array of buttons called buttonArray into my CheckWinner() function, maybe even CheckWinnerX() to keep the O and X separated, and test the .Text properties for the buttons in the array. I would start with the first group of buttons with the group size equal to the length of a side of the grid, and see if they are all "X", if so, produce a winner message, if not, then test the next group.

Comment: I'd also suggest a slight change to the question title - maybe something like... "Finding patterns in array using LINQ" or something?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using LINQ is the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to check *if* `Button.Text == "X"` *in* `every element of a horizontal row`. Following is a very basic way...

```
public void CheckWinner(Buttons[] buttonArray)
{
    int arrLength = buttonArray.Length; 
    int hCount = 0;
    //int vCount = 0;
    int root = (int)Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(arrLength));  

    for (int i = 0; i < arrLength ; i++)
    { 
        string bText = buttonArray[i].Text;

        hCount = i % root == 0? 0 : hCount;

        if(bText == "X") 
            hCount++;

        if(hCount == root) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Horizontal row winner found !");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

To check virtical and/or horizontal winner:

```
public void CheckWinner(Buttons[] buttonArray)
{
    int arrLength = buttonArray.Length; 
    int hCount = 0;
    Int vCount = 0;
    int root = (int)Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(arrLength));  

    for (int i = 0;  i < root;  i++)
    {
        hCount = 0;
        vCount = 0;
        for(int j = 0;  j < root; j++)
        {
           if(buttonArray[ (i * root) + j ].Text == "X")
              hCount++;

           if(buttonArray[ i + (root * j) ].Text == "X")
              vCount++;
        }

        if( hCount + vCount == 2 * root)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Horizontal and Virtical winner found !");
           break;
        } 
        else if ( hCount == root )
        { 
           Console.WriteLine("Horizontal winner found !");
           break;
        }
        else if ( vCount == root )
        { 
           Console.WriteLine("Virtical winner found !");
           break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This one is on the right track for what Im looking for but Im getting errors for the (i+1)%5

Comment: Yeah that one pops up when anything on the diagonal is clicked. What im trying to test for is I have a grid that is of side D x D. It is populated with a single dimensional array of Buttons, and I want to check, starting at 0, every D Buttons to see if their .Text property is "X" and if it is, I have  winner for a horizontal row.

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby: confused.com. do you want to check `text of every button` or `text of every 5th occurrence`?

Comment: text of every button. So after the buttons are created, when I click one, it changes the '.Text == "X"' and then runs the CheckWinner to see if there is a winner. For a 5x5 grid, 5 in a row wins. For a 3x3 grid its every 3 and so on. I'm starting out with horizontal because that is simply the first X amount of buttons in a row, starting with 0 where X is equal to the Sqrt(buttonarray.length)

Comment: thats perfect!! I think thats doing what I was looking for! What is the line `hCount = i % 5 == 0? 0 : hCount;` doing there?

Comment: Actually, it should be `i % Convert.ToInt32(root)`.  Otherwise, you're hard-coded to 5x5.

Comment: Okay, that is for: `if(i % 5 == 0){ hCount = 0;}else{ hCount = hCount}` in a single line. but you can replace it with `if(i % 5 == 0){ hCount = 0;}`. and `%` is for `modulus` @ScottMermelstein: my eyes are hurting now!... thanks :) !

Comment: I gave you a +1, Kaf.  Your answer is now generic for any number, and works right for horizontal.  Though I still don't see what's wrong with mine...  :-P

Comment: You guys rock, thank you so much. How can i give you +1 and all that (I'm new to posting on here)

Comment: Refresh your page and see if you can click `^` button next to each response you like to up vote. I am not sure if you have enough reputation to up vote but you can certainly accept the answer which would satisfy the unpaid volunteer who supported you from other side of the wire...

Comment: @Kaf If i want to modify the loop to check for the vertical win lines, can i keep the same structure or do I need to add another loop to keep could of the column that im checking? same principle as before start at ` 0, check 0+root, 0+2root` etc, and then start at `1, check 1+root, 1+2root`

Comment: For virtical check: for 5x5 you need to go like 0,5,10...or 1,6,11...or 2,7,12...etc. basically they are i % root ==0 for 1st col, i %root ==1 for 2nd col ...etc

Comment: Okay awesome so rather than increment a value for the column you can use the modulus because as you move up the modulus remainder will account for that?

Comment: Would i need to put a loop around around the vertical test to count from 0 until < root in order to have it running for root-1 times?

Comment: `for (x=0; x<root; x++){
    for (y=0; y<root; y++){
         buttonArray[x + (y * root)].Text` would that work for diagonal left to right starting at 0?

Comment: I guess thats the same as the vertical, maybe a seperate loop for the diags?

Comment: got it, it needs to be `buttonArray[j + (j * root)].Text`

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw my option in to the ring, though it looks like all the other answers work, as well.  Mine is a basic implementation.  It simply goes along each row, and checks to see if you have the same value in each row.  The Vertical version of this is as simple as rearranging my two for-loops, and the diagonal isn't too much harder.

It seems to me that the main trick of this question is just to show an understanding of array row and columns, and how to imitate a 2D array given only a 1D array.

For horizontal:

```
string CheckWinnerHorizontal(Button[] buttonArray) {
    int N = (int)Math.Sqrt(buttonArray.Length);
    for (int row = 0; row < N; ++row)
    {
        string winner = "";
        for (int col = 0; col < N; ++col)
        {
            string value = buttonArray[row * N + col].Text;
            if (winner == "") { winner = value; }
            else if (winner != value) { winner = "none"; }
        }
        if (winner != "none" && winner != "")
        {
            return winner;
        }
    }
    return "";
```

Comment: its saying cannot convert source type double to int for the Math.Sqrt?

Comment: Sorry.  Fixed in the edit.  Alternatively, if you know your grid size, just pass it in to the function, it'll be more efficient.  Since the grid is always a square of the grid size, I was capitalizing on that.

Comment: Errors are gone but nothing is happening when i get 5 Xs in a row. I dont have a method for the computer to go yet, so Im just focused on clicking a button, putting an X there, and then the program recognizing when I have 5 in a row for a win.

Comment: I feel pretty confident in the algorithm.  Are you sure it's being executed, and that the buttonArray you pass in has all the right buttons in the right order?  Can you step through and see what `value` is showing and if it matches what you clicked?

Comment: Yeah I clicked the 4th button in the row buttonArray[3] and when it came to that point in the loop it said value was "X"

Comment: If you have time, I'd love to know what happens if you click on the top five buttons, and look at winner on the `string value = buttonArray[row * N + col].Text;` line for the first five times.  (It should be: "", "X", "X", "X", "X", and then jump down outside of the loop and return winner.)

Comment: Kaf's example below works but I cant figure out what the 
`hCount = i % 5 == 0 ? 0 : hCount;` is supposed to be doing?

Comment: `else if (winner != value { winner = "none"; }` what is this for? I think there is a `syntax error` here.

Comment: @Kaf's example uses Modulus arithmetic to start new rows.  When i % root = 0, that means i is an even multiple of root.  So he goes through only one loop 25 times, while I go through two loops, five times each.  When his evaluates to zero, he restarts his counter, because he's on a new row.  Our loop logic is effectively the same.  If mine isn't working, it must be the logic that detects a winner.

Comment: For mine, on the first column, I keep the Text as a winner.  In any other column, if the Text doesn't match the original column, that means there's no winner on that row.  Actually, I could've added a break after the `winner = "none"` bit.

Comment: Bah.  I had missed a `)` in my code sample.  I'm surprised it compiled for you.  Maybe now you'll get the right result.

Comment: Finally !, Working in partnerships. I'll give you +1 `;)`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can give this a shot - I'll do by-rows here, by-cols should be very similar:

(edit - hah, evidently I can't read...but may remain a useful answer for others...since I've already proved I didn't pay attention to the OP, let me expand on that and fill in the vertical/diagonals...)

(LINQPad-ready)

```
void Main()
{
    // Quickish and very dirty way to generate the grid
    var lineLength = 3;
    var rnd = new Random();
    var gridSrc = 
        from r in Enumerable.Range(0, lineLength)
        from c in Enumerable.Range(0, lineLength)
        select new { Row = r, Col = c, Text = rnd.Next(0,2) > 0 ? "X" : "O" };
    var grid = gridSrc.ToArray();

    // ok, now for the query
    var horizontalWinners =
        // need the cell and it's index - this is one way to do that
        from cellTuple in grid.Select((cell, idx) => Tuple.Create(idx, cell))
        let idx = cellTuple.Item1
        let cell = cellTuple.Item2
        // figure out which row its in
        let row = idx / lineLength
        // figure out which column its in
        let col = idx % lineLength
        // for rows, group by row #
        group cell by row into byRow
        // only count if all cells in that row are same
        where byRow.All(rowCell => rowCell.Text == "X") 
             || byRow.All(rowCell => rowCell.Text == "O")
        // tell us what row (and who won)
        select new { byRow.Key, byRow.First().Text };

var verticalWinners =
    from cellTuple in grid.Select((cell, idx) => Tuple.Create(idx, cell))
    let idx = cellTuple.Item1
    let cell = cellTuple.Item2
    let row = idx / lineLength
    let col = idx % lineLength
    group cell by col into byCol
    where byCol.All(colCell => colCell.Text == "X") 
                 || byCol.All(colCell => colCell.Text == "O")
    select new { byCol.Key, byCol.First().Text };

var topLeftBottomRightDiagonalWinners =
    from cellTuple in grid.Select((cell, idx) => Tuple.Create(idx, cell))
    let idx = cellTuple.Item1
    let cell = cellTuple.Item2
    let row = idx / lineLength
    let col = idx % lineLength
    let fwdSlash = (row == col)
    group cell by fwdSlash into byDiag
    where byDiag.Key && byDiag.All(d => d.Text == byDiag.First().Text)
    select new { 
                 Text = byDiag.First().Text, 
                 Pos = string.Join("", byDiag.Select(c => Tuple.Create(c.Col, c.Row).ToString())) 
            };

var topRightBottomLeftDiagonalWinners =
    from cellTuple in grid.Select((cell, idx) => Tuple.Create(idx, cell))
    let idx = cellTuple.Item1
    let cell = cellTuple.Item2
    let row = idx / lineLength
    let col = idx % lineLength
    let backSlash = (row + col) == (lineLength - 1)
    group cell by backSlash into byDiag     
    where byDiag.Key && byDiag.All(d => d.Text == byDiag.First().Text)
    select new { 
               Text = byDiag.First().Text, 
               Pos = string.Join("", byDiag.Select(c => Tuple.Create(c.Col, c.Row).ToString())) 
            };

for(int r=0;r<lineLength;r++)
{
    for(int c=0;c<lineLength;c++)
    {
        Console.Write(grid[r*lineLength+c].Text + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
foreach(var row in horizontalWinners)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} wins on row {1}", row.Text, row.Key);
}
foreach(var col in verticalWinners)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} wins on col {1}", col.Text, col.Key);
}
foreach (var diag in topLeftBottomRightDiagonalWinners
                .Concat(topRightBottomLeftDiagonalWinners)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} wins on diagonal {1}", diag.Text, diag.Pos);     
}
}
```

Comment: OP want a non-LINQ solution

Comment: Hahah yeah the LINQ stuff I know is very powerful but at this point its just too hard for me to understand it by just cycling through web posts and MSDN library. Thank you though!

Comment: LINQ is definitely the way to go for this though. Very worth learning

Comment: I just need some interaction with a person to teach it to me because when i look through the explanations on threads and MSDN I get lost.

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby Don't suppose you're in the NYC area, eh?

Comment: @JerKimball if you're ever free for a chat to explain the concept to me I'd be more than willing to learn